# Can I emulate my NFC credit/bankcard with my phone?

Tags: samsung, 8.0-oreo, nfc, google-pay

down vote
favorite
Samsung Pay, Google Pay, Apple Pay or anything else isn't enabled in my country, but I do know that my card is using NFC. From what I have read there is a possibility that it can't be simply copied, because it actually doesn't transmit the card number and only encrypts something it sends. But I also read that some older cards don't use this yet and can be copied.

How can I find out which is the case? And in case it's an older card, how can I copy it onto my phone?

I have an Samsung S7 with Oreo (international model), maybe that matters because it has Samsung pay capabilities? I can also root it in case that is needed.